# Assignment Problem/Hungarian Algorithm - Table Input and Manipulation

Tags: c++, for-loop, 2d-vector, hungarian-algorithm, assignment-problem

I'm currently working on a college algorithms assignment, which involves creating an implementation for The Assignment Problem, or the Hungarian Algorithm. So far, I've coded a program that I believed was capable of performing the first 2 steps of the algorithm, which are:

- Step 1: In each row, subtract the minimum value in that row with each element.
- Step 2: In each column, subtract the minimum value in that column with each element.

Currently, my program is able to display 3 stages of the table (2D Vector) that it's manipulating:

- "Data", which is the table that is originally inputted.
- "Min Row Cots", which is the table after step 1 is performed.
- "Cost Matrix", which is the table after step 2 is performed.

The program correctly manipulates the table for the first example that I used, which is a 4x4 table with the following data:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | 59 | 52 | 53 |
| 62 | 67 | 59 | 49 |
| 55 | 64 | 58 | 51 |
| 58 | 60 | 54 | 48 |

However, this program cannot handle non-square tables, such as a 4x3.

Before trying to code steps 3-5 of the algorithm, I wanted to make sure that my program could handle uneven tables, so I came up with an example in the form of a 4x3 table. I wasn't sure if it would manipulate it correctly, but I atleast expected it to display the initial input table, 'data', correctly. However, this did not happen- When given the 4x3 example, the program displays an incorrectly rotated form of what the 'data' table should actually look like, and then proceeds to crash.

With this in mind, I was wondering if anyone had ideas as to what's happening, and possibly how I can fix it? If so, I would greatly appreciate it! My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class AssignmentProblem
{
private:
    int Row;
    int Column;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;
public:
    AssignmentProblem(std::vector<std::vector<int>> NewData, int NewRow, int NewColumn)
    {
        Row = NewRow;
        Column = NewColumn;
        data = NewData;
    }

    // ********************************************************************************* //
    // Take the minimum cost of each row, and adjust the matrix accordingly:
    std::vector<int> RowMinimums(std::vector<std::vector<int>> data)
    {
        std::vector<int> row_minimums;

        for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
        {
            int minimum = INT_MAX;
            for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++)
            {
                if (data[i][j] < minimum)
                {
                    minimum = data[i][j];
                }
            }
            row_minimums.push_back(minimum);
        }

        return row_minimums;
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> MinRowCosts(std::vector<std::vector<int>> data)
    {
        std::vector<int> row_minimums = RowMinimums(data);
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> min_row_costs;

        for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
        {
            std::vector<int> row;
            for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++)
            {
                row.push_back(data[j][i] - row_minimums[j]);
            }
            min_row_costs.push_back(row);
            row.clear();
        }

        return min_row_costs;
    }

    // ********************************************************************************* //
    // ********************************************************************************* //
    // Take the minimum cost of each column, and adjust the matrix accordingly:
    std::vector<int> ColumnMinimums(std::vector<std::vector<int>> min_row_costs)
    {
        std::vector<int> column_minimums;

        for (int i = 0; i < Column; i++)
        {
            int minimum = INT_MAX;
            for (int j = 0; j < Row; j++)
            {
                if (min_row_costs[i][j] < minimum)
                {
                    minimum = min_row_costs[i][j];
                }
            }
            column_minimums.push_back(minimum);
        }

        return column_minimums;
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> MinColumnCosts(std::vector<std::vector<int>> min_row_costs)
    {
        std::vector<int> column_minimums = ColumnMinimums(min_row_costs);
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> min_column_costs;

        for (int i = 0; i < Column; i++)
        {
            std::vector<int> column;
            for (int j = 0; j < Row; j++)
            {
                column.push_back(min_row_costs[j][i] - column_minimums[j]);
            }
            min_column_costs.push_back(column);
            column.clear();
        }

        return min_column_costs;
    }

    // ********************************************************************************* //

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> calculateCostMatrix(std::vector<std::vector<int>> data)
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> min_row_costs = MinRowCosts(data);

        std::cout << "Min Row Costs = " << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "< ";
            for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++)
            {
                std::cout << min_row_costs[j][i] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << " >" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::vector<std::vector<int>> cost_matrix = MinColumnCosts(min_row_costs);

        std::cout << "Cost Matrix = " << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "< ";
            for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++)
            {
                std::cout << cost_matrix[i][j] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << " >" << std::endl;
        }
        return cost_matrix;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int Row = 4;
    int Column = 3; // Broken Example (4x3 Table).
    //int Column = 4; // Working Example (4x4 Table).

    //std::vector<std::vector<int>> data  = {{56,59,52,53}, {62,67,59,49}, {55,64,58,51}, {58,60,54,48}}; // Working Example (4x4 Table).
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data = {{11,12,18,40},{14,15,13,22},{11,17,19,23}};  // Broken Example (4x3 Table)

    std::cout << "Data = " << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "< ";
        for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++)
        {
            std::cout << data[j][i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << " >" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    AssignmentProblem AP(data, Column, Row);

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> costs = AP.calculateCostMatrix(data);

    return 0;
}
```

Sidenote: I apologize if my code is hard to read or follow.. I'm still fairly new to programming, and am working on readability.

Comment: *I was wondering if anyone had ideas as to what's happening, and possibly how I can fix it?* -- [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: This might be a good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: `std::vector<int> RowMinimums(std::vector<std::vector<int>> data)` -- This should be passed by const reference, not by value: `std::vector<int> RowMinimums(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& data)`.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> data` -- Also, it is confusing that you are naming your parameters the same as the name of the data member of the `AssignmentProblem` class.  You have two `data`'s floating around in your program when you call functions such as `RowMinimums`.  Rename your member variable to something more descriptive other than `data`, and leave the parameter name alone, so that the code is less confusing (and possibly the confusion is messing up your program logic).

Comment: Now that I look at it, why are you passing `data` to any of those functions, other than the `AssignmentProblem` constructor?  The data is already there in the `data` member variable, no?

Comment: Also, it seems you are getting mixed up in which index is the row and which index is the column.  `data[row][column]` means that the left-most index is the row and the rightmost index is the column.  Your code reverses this -- is this intentional?  But the bottom line is that you should have discovered any of these discrepancies if you debugged your code, and not have others step in and debug the code for you (which is highly discouraged here for someone to not debug their own code -- that can be worthy of your question being downvoted).

Comment: PaulMcKenzie, Thank you for your input. It has helped me make my code a bit more readable by removing unnecessary parameters, and changing some variable names. I had my code run through the columns before the rows in some cases, because that's what seemed to yield the correct output for the 4x4 example. However, I have managed to change the code to always investigate the rows first, and still give out the correct output. I haven't used the actual debugger, but I have been running through the program manually.

Comment: I apologize if this post was taken as me just asking people to completely fix my code for me.. My intention was to ask for suggestions that can point me in the right direction, and atleast help me through this "wall" that I'm stuck at to some degree. The input you gave has helped me make my code more understandable, so perhaps that'll make it easier for me to figure out how I can get it to work with tables that do not have a uniform row-column ratio.

Answer (score 1):

##### Row and column subscripts transposed

You have transposed row and column coordinates in many places in your program. Most of the references to `data[j][i]` should put `i` first, because `i` is the row subscript.

I recommend dropping `i` and `j`, and replacing them with `row` and `col`. That way you won't lose track of which subscript should go first. Here, for example, is one of your functions, after making that change.

Note: *the row subscript always goes first*, e.g., `min_row_costs[row][col]`, even when the outer loop is a column loop.

```cpp
    // Take the minimum cost of each column, and adjust the matrix accordingly:
    std::vector<int> ColumnMinimums(std::vector<std::vector<int>> min_row_costs)
    {
        std::vector<int> column_minimums;

        for (int col = 0; col < Column; col++)
        {
            int minimum = INT_MAX;
            for (int row = 0; row < Row; row++)
            {
                if (min_row_costs[row][col] < minimum)
                {
                    minimum = min_row_costs[row][col];
                }
            }
            column_minimums.push_back(minimum);
        }

        return column_minimums;
    }
```

Similarly, it is wrong to reference `row_minimums[j]`, when j is a column subscript. That should be `row_minimums[i]`, or, better yet, `row_minimums[row]`.

##### Call function `size` to get `n_rows` and `n_cols`

*Side note:* The vector carries with it the number of rows and columns.

```cpp
void example(std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix)
{
    // You do not have to pass the sizes as parameters.
    // Call member function `size` to get `n_rows` and `n_cols`.
    auto const n_rows{ matrix.size() };
    auto const n_cols{ matrix.front().size() };

    // There is no guarantee, however, that every row has 
    // the same number of columns. If there is a possibility 
    // that row-length is not uniform, you can always check.
    for (auto const& row : matrix)
        if (row.size() != n_cols)
            throw std::runtime_error("row size varies.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! It helped alot with making my code a bit more readable through removal of unnecessary parameters, and some variable name changes. However, I notice that you're code suggestion seems to check if the matrix is uniform, and throw an error if it isn't. I don't wish to throw an error in this case, but I would rather the program be able to handle the non-uniform table and also be able to perform the hungarian algorithm on it. I believe I'm starting to find a way to get it to work, but I'm not entirely sure yet.

Comment: I'm thinking when I print the matrices, and perhaps when I'm calculating all of the values within them too, I need to put some form of 'if' statement that checks if the number of rows equals the number of columns, and if it doesn't (if the number of columns is greater than the number of rows, for example), break out of the 'for' loop before 'int i', or what is now 'int row' exceeds 'n_rows'.